# Popover row on clicking a button inside a listview

Tags: android, listview, user-interface

[image: Dropbox]
<sub>(source: [javatechig.com](http://javatechig.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/list-view-screenshots.png))</sub>

I am trying to achieve the functionality shown in the first part of the above image. But after exhaustive searching, I can't find a way to do it.

How would I implement something like that?